# How to divide the output of Markdown in two lines?

Tags: bash, r-markdown

I am trying to get the OS and CPU version and for that I use the following command in Rmarkdown

```
uname -an
```

To which it gives me a very long output (Darwin MacBook-Air-de-Julio.local 21.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.4.0: Fri Mar 18 00:47:26 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.101.4~15/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101 arm64) which cuts me in half when I render it to pdf.

My question is: How do I make the output divided into two lines when rendering to pdf?

Comment: are you looking to *just* split the line or do you also need to extract the `OS` and `CPU` components? please update the question with the expected output and the code you've tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way to divide it roughly in half at the date is to replace `": "` with `'\n'` using `sed`, e.g.

```
$ uname -an | sed 's/: /\n/'
Darwin MacBook-Air-de-Julio.local 21.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.4.0
Fri Mar 18 00:47:26 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.101.4~15/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101 arm64
```

Comment: Thanks you very much!! It worked exactly us I wanted to.

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with your scripting!